# How to split string in fragment android?

Tags: java, split

my text file name test.txt read from asset. I have UniversityName-1829,UniversityName-1983,UniversityName-1999. What I want is Only UniversityName in fragment Layout and the number value i want to use it later.

Comment: Please post the code for your first attempt and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Split it by commas and use regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split each String using [substring():](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

It works this way : `String substr = mysourcestring.subString(startIndex,endIndex);`

for Ex you have an string like this:

```
String tmp = "UniversityName-1829";
```

then you can access the university name :

```
String uni = tmp.subString(0, tmp.indexOf("-");
```

this line will cut out the university name,in fact it will get the characters from the beginning of string to this  char:  ' - '

for the number use this:

```
String num = tmp.subString(tmp.indexOf("-"));
```

this will get all the characters after ' - '